# HTML templating like PHP templating

Tags: php, html, templates

I know things like these have been asked and answered several times before, is it just that I can't grasp the idea easily or too hard to accept that things are really like this and that.

I know that HTML is used for Front-End where the tedious work is done in the Client, and PHP is working behind the scenes (Server-Side). With so many regulations, instruction, standards, so on and so forth.. I believed I have already confused myself with these stuffs, making things (new and old) hard for me to chew and understand especially when it comes to their best uses...

Anyway, I have created a web application based on the concept of MVC tho I didn't used the strong fundamentals of the topic nor a framework, I separated the Logic, Rules and Design concerns by my own.

Unfortunately, I wound up with some issues similar to which is the right way to do the things, how this should be implemented, etc...

I end up needing to template the HTML, however, since I've used HTML as HTML itself, I end up updating/editing each and every affected file (for. eg. a web page header), unlike when I used PHP before, literally a file with a .php extension, where I can fully utilize templating, however, i read somewhere that it is not a good practice because it breaks the HTML.. so which one should I follow and how can I solve my problem, should I move to .php and then create a template page, or is there a way I could do such with HTML? if there is any, how can it be done?

Please for the meantime, don't point me to frameworks available, I want to understand basic things first before studying frameworks...

Anyone, please...

Edit...
so this is just fine and that it doesn't have any drawbacks...
main.php

```
 <?php php stuffs ?>
 <html>
 <body>
  HTML stuffs and some <?php php stuffs ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML has no templating capability.

It has frames and iframes, but they come with significant drawbacks and only provide include functionality.

You should use a proper templating language. This can run on the client, server or build system.

I'd recommend against running it on the client. It adds an unnecessary dependency that your visitors (including search engine indexers) have to fulfil.

PHP will do the job (it straddles the border of being a programming language and a templating language). My personal preference is for [Template-Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/).

TT can run in your build system via the [ttree utility](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/tools/ttree.html), or you can run it on your server. There is [a tutorial](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/tutorial/Web.html) covering how to build websites using it.

If, and when, you move to building websites with more demanding server side requirements, then you can continue to use TT as it is supported but most of the web frameworks in Perl land (e.g. the [dancer module for TT](https://metacpan.org/module/Dancer%3a%3aTemplate%3a%3aTemplateToolkit) and the [catalyst module for TT](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst%3a%3aView%3a%3aTT). Note that those links go to the hardcode documentation for the modules, and if you plan to use one of the frameworks you should start with a higher level tutorial)

Comment: I guess, its inevitable to intermix things altogether as long it is the most efficient and effective way of doing things. I guess I really have to sway a little away from following standards and keeping them diligently followed in real life, maybe, just maybe, as not all rules can apply to all. That means you can always create a 99.99% perfect application and the .01% is always available as the room for improvement or changes.. So, its so much for me following this should be and that should be... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

HTML is a markup language - in other words it can mark up text to display to the user.

It cannot do any of the dynamic type functions you might need in a web application - like updating the date, for example.

So it is best to think of HTML documents, just like you might think of a Word document, a load of text that is displayed to the user.

As soon as you want to start using templates to display dynamic information (stuff from a database, maybe), you're going to need a scripting language.  PHP is good for this.

I've had good experience with [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) - a php templating engine.

---

On a side note, learning a framework can be a really useful part of the learning the basics.  Most frameworks *force* you to do things in a good way, and sometimes the things they make you write in your code may seem a bit strange or illogical, suddenly one day the penny will drop and you'll realise why what you've been forced to do is sound from an engineering point of view.

Comment: i think i need to clear my fear and doubts first, i really think i need to learn the basics before learning the frameworks, as most of the time, things are done by the books anymore... hopefully, i can pick it up fast

Answer (score 0):

You can look @ javascript templating. I suggest you to give a try to http://mustache.github.com/

Answer (score 0):

[Modest](https://github.com/goalzen/modest) is a template system that's supposed to look and feel like HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to do HTML templating with PHP, is to use one of these popular templating engines :

- **[Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)**
- **[Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation)**
- **[Latte](https://github.com/nette/latte)**
- **[Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/)**

---

Alternatively, you can just put placeholders in your HTML that look something like `<% variablename %>`. Just load your HTML, do a regex do find all placeholders and replace them with the corresponding variables.

---

Alternatively, you can load your HTML, parse it as a [**DOM document**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and then modify your DOM. I created the library [**DOM Query**](https://github.com/PHPPowertools/DOM-Query) to be able to do this with a jQuery-like syntax, but you could use vanilla PHP or one of several other libraries as well.

---

Alternatively, you can do some HTML templating in frontend with JavaScript. If you want to do HTML templating both on frontend and backend, you might want to consider using **[Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/)**, because Mustache templates can be used both in frontend (with JavaScript) and in backend (with PHP).