# Html theme for every page

Tags: php, html, css

I'm creating a theme for my `php` project. I want to decrease my code amount by creating a simple `theme.html` page and include that to every page.

Can you help me guys?

Example `theme.html`:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to panel</h1>
<ul>
  <li><a class="home"  href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a class="about" href="#">About us</a></li>
  <li><a class="contact" href="#">Contact us</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- content -->
<div class="content"><!-- other page codes will write here --></div>
<!-- content -->
</body>
<html>
```

And now i want to include this code to `index.html` and write form codes to content div? Help me...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML templating like PHP templating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194611/html-templating-like-php-templating)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using php
 for that you have to save the files `.php` like `index.html into index.php` 
then include the file like below

```
<?php include 'theme.php';?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [twig](https://twig.symfony.com/) which is a great template manager for php (initially made for Symfony) and really easy to use.